# udev rule symlink pointing wrong?

Tags: linux

I have a USB box for a rfid reader that I plug into my RPi (model 2).
It shows up as either `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyUSB4` - or something else.

I would like to use udev rule to create a symbolic link to `/dev/ttyUSBrr`.

I have tried many different udev rules.

Sometimes the rule doesn't catch anything or if it does, the symlink points to `/dev/bus/001/006` - and the application cannot use that.

For instance this very simple rule:

```
ATTRS{product}=="FTR232R USB UART", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBrr"
```

If I try to add more keys like `"KERNEL=='USB'"` or something, the rule doesn't catch anything?

I am definitely missing something in the understanding of devices and udev.

Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Here is the output of the udevadm query:

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

```
  looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':

    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"
    ATTRS{latency_timer}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3.2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="FT232R USB UART"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3.2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="90mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0600"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="A9Z94ZQY"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="22646"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="FT232R USB UART"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="7761"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="29"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0608"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="3"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="34"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9512"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="20980000.usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="25"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.36+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb':
    KERNELS=="20980000.usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
    ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
    ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
    ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
    ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
    ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
    ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
    ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001405"
    ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 690 msecs (69 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
    ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
    ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
    ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
    ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
    ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
    ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
    ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
    ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
    ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x20001700"
    ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
    ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
    ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4c"
    ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
    ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
    ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 1490 msecs (149 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
    ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
    ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc':
    KERNELS=="soc"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you match against a parent device (the `*S` rules) all your conditions must match against the same parent device. So basically you have just two devices to match:

1. The proper device you want to link.
2. A single antecesor of your device, your choice.

The device for 1 has two sensible choices: `SUBSYSTEM=="tty"` or `KERNEL="ttyUSB*`.

And for the device for 2 you want the USB one. Instead of `ATTRS{product}=="FT232R USB UART"`, my advice is to use the `ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"`, as it is expected to be more predictable.

So the rule becomes (obviously untested):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBrr"
```

Comment: The rule you gave me works.
Only - I had to put it into a rule file with name 95-xxx (lower priority).

And thanks for the explanation. Can't say I have understood everything about devices yet, but i will sit down and study it some more.